# Linq Select nested lists

Tags: c#, linq, list, mongodb

my mongodb model looks like this

```
 "clienteId" : "123",
 "devices" : [
     {
             "deviceId" : "234",
             "deviceType" : "ios"
     }
  ]
```

i'm calling findAll on this collection and trying to transform it a list of objects that looks like this

```
 public List<Client> clients { get; set; }
 public class Client
 {
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    public List<Device> devices;
    public class Device
    {
       public string DeviceId { get; set; }
       public string DeviceType { get; set; }
     }
  }
```

I want to use LINQ, how can I transform the inner list?

Answer (score 0):

Found it, it was much simpler then i thought :)

```
clientes = cursor.Select(c => new Client()
{
     ClientId = c.ClientId,
     devices = c.Devices.Select(d => new Client.Device()
     {
         DeviceId = d.DeviceId,
         DeviceType = d.DeviceType
     }).ToList()
 }).ToList()
```